# How do I import a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm struggling with how I can import my functional component in another component (in ReservationForm.js to be precise).

I tried it the *regular way but it didn't seem to work.

`* import PersonalForm from './PersonalForm'`

Maybe I coded it in the wrong way that makes it impossible for me to 'tag' the function when I want to import it.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Card from "../UI/Card";

const PersonalForm = React.memo(props => {
   some form
})
```

It does not contain an `export default` because when I tried to add that it gave errors.

Comment: Try `export const PersonalForm = ...`, and importing it with `import { PersonalForm } from "./PersonalForm"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```js
// PersonalForm.js
const PersonalForm = ...;
export PersonalForm;

// otherModule.js
import { PersonalForm } from './PersonalForm';
```

OR

```js
// PersonalForm.js
const PersonalForm = ...;
export default PersonalForm;

// otherModule.js
import PersonalForm from './PersonalForm';
```

There should be no more than one `export default` statement in each file.
You can have as many `export` statements as you want in each file.

> It does not contain an export default because when I tried to add that it gave errors.

Could you provide those errors?

Answer (score 0):

May i know what error it gave after using export default?

It should be something like :

```
export default function PersonalForm (props) {
```